# Error code on php script when using Magento 2 Marketplace Module

Tags: magento2, marketplace

I'm using this Magento 2 Marketplace Extension: https://landofcoder.com/magento-2-marketplace-extension.html/ I get this error when I go into the marketplace admin to add or remove a seller or any other feature.

Fatal error: Declaration of Lof\MarketPlace\Model\Condition\Sql\Builder::attachConditionToCollection(Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection $collection, Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Combine $combine) must be compatible with Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Sql\Builder::attachConditionToCollection(Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection $collection, Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Combine $combine): void in /home/firerock/public_html/devmjx/app/code/Lof/MarketPlace/Model/Condition/Sql/Builder.php on line 26

Do you know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is paid extension you can contact them directly it will be good option.
Also, you can reinstall it or delete seller and it's related content.